# Requests throwing a 400 error with user input

Tags: python, api, tkinter

i'm fairly new to Python and this is my first attempt and building something. I'm creating a weather app where the user types out their city and it returns weather data regarding theri city. When i create a variable and set it equal to the string of a city, it works perfectly, however, when i try to do the same thing from user input, i get the 400 status code error.

This works perfectly

```
city_input = Entry(root, bd=4)
city_name = 'Houston'
complete_url = base_url + str(city_name) + '&appid=' + api_key
response = requests.get(complete_url, headers=headers)
print(response.status_code)
x = response.json()
```

This throws a 400 status code

```
city_input = Entry(root, bd=4)
city_name = city_input.get().title()
complete_url = base_url + str(city_name) + '&appid=' + api_key
response = requests.get(complete_url, headers=headers)
print(response.status_code)
x = response.json()
```

I've tried printing the value from the input to make sure it pops up as the city name but still no dice. I tried creating headers to help but that also didn't seem to work. I appreciate any and all help!

Comment: You created an Entry, then you *immediately* called `.get()` on it.  You received an empty string, of course - the user hasn't even seen the Entry yet, much less had any chance to type anything into it.  Code like that would normally be found in a function specified as the `command=` option of a Button, so that the user can indicate that they have actually entered something.

Comment: @jasonharper so right now, I have that submit button taking you to a label which displays the information. Do i have to assign city_name.get() into that label as well?

Comment: Which submit button? Update your code with the changes and the errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as @jasonharper mentioned. I was called .get() immediately after creating the text box. I placed my code into a function and used a button and set that function to my command. Thanks to everyone for the help!